# CakePHP 2.0+: Retrieving POST data from Js->submit form in controller

Tags: php, cakephp, post, xmlhttprequest

I am using $this->Js->submit to pass a value to my controller asynchronously and than update a div (id = #upcoming). Somehow I cannot save/retrieve the value of the field 'test' which is passed to my controller. Firebug tells me that the correct value is passed. What am I doing wrong?

View file (playlist.ctp):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Add', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Gods', 'action' => 'add')));
echo $this->Form->input('test');       
echo $this->Js->submit('Addddd', array(
'url' => array(
    'controller' => 'Gods',
    'action' => 'add'
),
'update' => '#upcoming'
));
echo $this->Form->end();

echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('inline' => 'true'));
```

Controller action:

```
public function add()
{
$this->autoLayout = false;
   $this->layout = 'ajax';
$link = $this->request->data['Add']['test'];
$this->set('test',$link);
}
```

And its view file (add.ctp):

```
<?php
echo $test;
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried pr($link) in the controller method? Or just send it to a log file if you prefer that. That way you can see if the data is received.

If so, I think there is nothing returned because of

```
 $this->autoLayout = false;
```

Try it without this. It will still call the ajax layout instead of the default.
Otherwise you have to manualy call the render function

```
$this->render('add');
```

**EDIT**
As explained in the comments below, make sure your views are in the right place. (that would be the view folder associated with the controller)

Comment: Jeroen, thanks for your reply. But the problem is that $link is empty, meaning that $this->request->data['Add']['test']; somehow doesn't work. If I just echo something random like echo "blub"; in the controller, it correctly displays "blub" after the Ajax call. That means it isn't related to the Layout. What else could it be? Is there a specific way to save Post data from Js->submit?

Comment: I tried you code and it works for me. Is everything in the same 'Gods' controller? Like View/Gods/playlist.ctp and View/Gods/add.ctp?

Comment: Jeroen, thanks for your help! I had the view files in View/PlayList/ (for whatever reason). Thanks, I knew it was something "simple" I was overseeing. Still getting used to Cake I guess :-)